# How can I tell which DNS server is being queried (Raspbian Lite)

Tags: networking, dns, raspbian

I am using the latest Raspbian Lite Linux and I cannot figure out how to get it to tell me which DNS server my queries are being sent to. Everything that I try is only returning the localhost address (127.0.0.1), which of course is referring to the local DNS cache. However, I want to know which upstream DNS server is being used (in my case, I want to verify that it is using the Google DNS servers, not the router).

Here's are some details:

- `reslovconf` is installed.
- I have not set any custom DNS servers in `/etc/resolvconf.conf`.
- The contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` are automatically generated by `resolvconf`. It contains the line `nameserver 127.0.0.1`. Manual changes to this file do not persist (as expected).
- In `/etc/network/interfaces` I have the following line in my network interface settings for wlan0: `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

What I have tried:

- `dig` returns `SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)`
- `nslookup` returns `Server: 127.0.0.1  Address: 127.0.0.1#53`
- `cat /etc/resolv.conf` returns `nameserver 127.0.0.1`
- `nmcli dev show | grep DNS` returns no results. There are no DNS related entries at all in a full `nmcli dev show`.

Any recommendations beyond what I've tried so far?

**For clarity:** DNS is working fine. I just want to know what upstream server is being queried.

Comment: What does `tcpdump` or `wireshark` show going on for DNS packets?

Comment: @thrig I don't know why I hadn't thought about using packet capture. I guess I was too stuck on finding a command to spit out a the response I wanted to think about all the options. I'll give it a shot and let you know, though I expect that you've answered my question.

Comment: Sounds like you have a DNS resolver installed. Usual ones being bind9 (named), dnsmasq or unbound. Check your `ps ax` for a process matching these names, then look for the corresponding configuration files, ...

Comment: @SYN you are correct. This particular Raspberry Pi is wifi-sharing device, and I installed `dnsmasq` as part of the initial configuration a few months ago, but I had entirely forgotten about that. Running `service dnsmasq status` revealed the info I was looking for. Would you mind making your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Packet capture is probably a bit premature at this point. Since you can see the requests going to `udp/53` on localhost, you can just check `netstat -tlpn` or `lsof -i udp:53` for what program is listening on that port and then look at its configuration to see what upstream servers it has configured. It would be more complete as well since a capture would just get the servers it happened to go out to that one time.

Comment: @Bratchley Sweet. On this system it is `systemd-resolve` for example. Just listing what's listening on port 53 is golden: `sudo lsof -i udp:53` did it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, sounds like you have a DNS resolver installed. Usual ones being bind9 (named), dnsmasq or unbound.

Check your `ps ax` for a process matching these names, then look for the corresponding configuration files.

Comment: Repeating what I said above in the comments: I had installed `dnsmasq` a few months ago and forgotten about it. By running `service dnsmasq status` I was able to see the upstream DNS servers being used.

Answer (score -1):

You probably using `dnsmasq` , try running

```
ps -ef | grep dnsmasq
```

This should give you the config file for dnsmasq which used, then just look into it and see which DNS are used as forwards for `dnsmasq`.